# How can I bring a pyGTK program to visibility, at any time, with a keypress?

Tags: python, pygtk

This question isn't about how to grab the keypress, i'm using accelators for that(but fi thats the wrong way by all means correct me)

Once i start my program, i press ESC to hide it with window.hide_all().

the user may then do other things in other programs, etc, but I want to make it so whenever the user presses, for example, alt + backspace, my program comes back to visibility

Very much like in unix system, pressing alt + f2 fires up the GUI launcher.

bonus: plus what happens if the key combination i set (alt + backspace) is already a shortcut for something in the user's system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to arrange that in the window manager. If the program doesn't have the input focus, it doesn't even receive keystrokes.